# Basic currency conversion app

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

I am trying to make a very basic app that tells me the currency conversion. I manage to covert from dollars to INR pretty easily by putting a value in the dollar textfield and that gets converted to INR after multiplying it by 60. However when I want to find out the value of a dollar and divide a value in the INR text field by 60, both text fields pop up message saying

> Please enter a value

This is the code that I wrote:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dollar: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var rupee: UITextField!

@IBAction func convert(sender: AnyObject) {

    var dollarNew = dollar.text.toInt()

    if (dollarNew != nil) {
            dollarNew = dollarNew! * 60
            rupee.text = "\(dollarNew!)"
    } else {
        rupee.text = "Please enter a value"
    }

    var rupeeNew = rupee.text.toInt()

    if (rupeeNew != nil) {
        rupeeNew = rupeeNew! / 60
        dollar.text = "\(rupeeNew!)"
    } else {
        dollar.text = "Please enter a value"
    }


}
```

I am extremely new at programming and at xCode as well. Can anyone help by telling me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Read through your code. Under what conditions do both text fields show the message?

Comment: Hey, so i played around with the code a bit and removed 'else' from both my 'if statements'. Doing that helped me get rid of the problem. Either way, condition is actually such that if there is no value in either of those text fields i.e. 'dollar' or 'rupee' then the message that should pop up in the other field is "Please enter a value". If it is not nil, then multiply or divide by 60 depending upon what field the value is entered.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is the following:

You enter something into the rupee field. Because the dollar field is empty the code goes into the first else clause and sets the text in the rupee field to "Please enter a value".

Then you get the text from the rupee field and try to get the int value. But this isn't convertible to int. Therefore you get nil. And enter the second else clause. This sets "Please enter a value" to the dollar field.